ways to calculate the accuracy of a object detection model
In case of classification, we will calculate the accuracy by performance of model on test dataset.
# accuracy = correct_predictions/total_number_of_test_data
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
acc = accuracy_score(y_truth, y_predicted)
print(acc)

But in the case of Object detection, instead of manually looking into the drawn bounding box to ensure performance of model, Is there any other way to evaluate the model that will gives us the confident about performance of model, as we acquired from accuracy used in classification problem?
